# Converting to array

Tags: c#, text-files

I have addres book app, and want to write the final result into a text file. I am having hard time to convert my list to an array so that I could execute the `WriteAllLines` command.

Interface:

```
abstract class PhoneBookCore {
    protected string _group;

    public PhoneBookCore(string group) {
        this._group=group;
    }

    public abstract void Add(PhoneBookCore d);
}

class Contect: PhoneBookCore {
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _phoneNumber;
    private string _addres;

    public Contect(string group, string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber, string addres)
        : base(group) {
        this._firstName=firstName;
        this._addres=addres;
        this._lastName=lastName;
        this._phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
    }
}

class Group: PhoneBookCore {
    private List<PhoneBookCore> elements=new List<PhoneBookCore>();

    public List<PhoneBookCore> elementsList {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Group(string name)
        : base(name) {

    }

    public override void Add(PhoneBookCore d) {
        elements.Add(d);
    }
}
```

This is where I stuck

```
class DataOptins {
    public string Save(Group g) {
        foreach(var item in g) {
            string[] arr=g.elementsList.ToArray();  // <---- :(

        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path, arr); // <---- :(
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use: List.ToArray(); To convert your list to array

Comment: g.elementsList is of type public List<PhoneBookCore>. Why are you casting that to string[] . Should it not be PhoneBookCore[] ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is flawed in many ways, but I will focus on your specific question for now.

First, you have to override the `ToString()` method in the class *Contect*:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}{1}{4}", _firstName, "\t", _lastName, _phoneNumber, _addres);
}
```

(This is just an example, have your own format of course)

And now have such code to make the list into array of strings:

```
public string Save(Group g)
{
    string[] lines = g.elementsList.ConvertAll(p => p.ToString()).ToArray();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path, lines );
}
```

Now with this and with your current code you will get an exception since `g.elementsList` will always be *null*. Why? Because you never assign it. Having other private member is all good, but the compiler can't know that when you call to `elementsList` you actually want the private member `elements`.

Change the code to:

```
private List<PhoneBookCore> elements = new List<PhoneBookCore>();
public List<PhoneBookCore> elementsList { get { return new List<PhoneBookCore>(elements); } }
```

And you won't have "null exception" anymore. Note that I made the public property return a copy of the list so that the calling code won't be able to change your private member.

Comment: it comes out with: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." how should i resolve this? my call in the main is :
DataOptins l = new DataOptins();
             l.Save(groupA);

Comment: string[] lines = g.elementsList.ConvertAll(phoneBookCore => phoneBookCore.ToString()).ToArray();

Comment: Yeah, that's due to "flawed in many ways" I mentioned. I will edit my post in a short while.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I'm so wondering how can you make an answer in amazingly speed.

Comment: @Ken cheers, will delete mine too shortly. 8 minutes is ubber slow by the way!

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Super speedy!! I'd like to +1 for this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't `foreach`. Just call `ToArray` on your list. However, before doing that, you need to select the actual string property in the elements of the group.
`Group.elementsList` is a list of `PhoneBookCore` objects. You can't convert them to `string` - at least not the way your class currently looks like. So, either select that string property you actually want to have:

```
public string Save(Group g)
{
    string[] arr = g.elementsList.Select(x => x.StringProperty).ToArray();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path,arr);
}
```

Or override `ToString` in `PhoneBookCore` and use that:

```
public string Save(Group g)
{
    string[] arr = g.elementsList.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path,arr);
}
```

At last, you can actually drop the call to `ToArray` altogether, because there exists an overload of `WriteAllLines` that accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public string Save(Group g)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path, g.elementsList.Select(x => x.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'PhoneBook.PhoneBookCore[]' to 'string[]'

Answer (score 1):

1) If `Add` method is not a requirement for all derived class, rather declare it as **virtual** than **abstract**.

2) Override `ToString()` of your `Contect` class. If it's necessary, override for `PhoneBookCore` also. In the `Contect` class it would be like:

```
public override String ToString() {
    return
        (new[] { _firstName, _lastName, _phoneNumber, _addres }).Aggregate((a, b) => a+"\t"+b);
}
```

the rule to aggregate them depends on your requirement.

3) Make you `Group` class implement `IEnumerable<String>` for semantics meaningful thus you don't need to expose `elementsList`. You'll need to implement `GetEnumerator()` for this, but it's simple to:

```
partial class Group: PhoneBookCore, IEnumerable<String> {
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<String> GetEnumerator() {
        return elements.Select(x => x.ToString()).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

When you've done all of these three things, then you can simply implement your `Save` method like:

```
public string Save(Group g) {
    string[] arr=g.ToArray(); // <---- :(
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path, arr); // <---- :(

    // notice: you did not show what to return in original code
}
```

4) Suggesting that correct your class name `DataOptins` to `DataOptions`, and `Contect` to `Contact`.

Okay, following would be the completion of code(except what `Save` returns):

```
abstract class PhoneBookCore {
    protected string _group;

    public PhoneBookCore(string group) {
        this._group=group;
    }

    public virtual void Add(PhoneBookCore d) {
    }
}

class Contect: PhoneBookCore {
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _phoneNumber;
    private string _addres;

    public override String ToString() {
        return
            (new[] { _firstName, _lastName, _phoneNumber, _addres }).Aggregate((a, b) => a+"\t"+b);
    }

    public Contect(string group, string firstName, string lastName, string phoneNumber, string addres)
        : base(group) {
        this._firstName=firstName;
        this._addres=addres;
        this._lastName=lastName;
        this._phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
    }
}

class Group: PhoneBookCore, IEnumerable<String> {
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<String> GetEnumerator() {
        return elements.Select(x => x.ToString()).GetEnumerator();
    }

    private List<PhoneBookCore> elements=new List<PhoneBookCore>();

    public List<PhoneBookCore> elementsList {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Group(string name)
        : base(name) {
    }

    public override void Add(PhoneBookCore d) {
        elements.Add(d);
    }
}

class DataOptins {
    public string Save(Group g) {
        string[] arr=g.ToArray(); // <---- :(
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Path, arr); // <---- :(

        // notice: you did not show what to return in original code
    }
}
```

Comment: @darko: Not at all. You have an accepting answer, but just I thought that seems you need more help on this.